# Editing old commits non-interactively with git

Tags: git, scripting, rebase

I know how to edit an old commit manually:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:'%h %s'
    60e5ed9 Second commit
    0fbc8ed First commit
$ git rebase --interactive 0fbc8ed # Going back to 'First commit'
    # * $EDITOR gets fired up *
    # change 'pick 0fbc8ed' to 'edit 0fbc8ed'
$ echo 'Hello Kitteh!' > some_file
$ git add some_file
$ git commit --amend -m 'some message'
$ git rebase --continue # Go back
```

The problem here:

`git rebase --interactive` fires up an editor, which is kinda bad for scripting purpose. Is there any way to overcome this, i.e. directly passing `edit 0fbc8ed` to the `git rebase` command?

Is it idiotic what I'm attempting or is there maybe a clearer, alternative way to do this?

There is a similar question, but in my case I want to change `pick` to `edit`:

[How can I automatically accept what git rebase --interactive presents to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548693/how-can-i-automatically-accept-what-git-rebase-interactive-presents-to-me)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I easily fixup a past commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103589/how-can-i-easily-fixup-a-past-commit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for "git filter-branch" and the option "--commit-filter". Look at the manual page here exists a example section.

Comment: `git commit --fixup` plus `git rebase -i --autosquash` is much better

Comment: yea you are right, but --fixup prepend on your message a "fixup!" - or? and you can only change the subject line of a commit?

Comment: It is `git commit --fixup <SHA-to-fix>`, and then `rebase -i --autosquash <SHA-to-fix>~1` squashes the fixup commit with the one you're fixing, and the magic happens

Comment: This looks promising.
But `rebase -i` still spawns an editor? But I guess I can set `EDITOR` to `/bin/true` to auto-accept it

Edit: Yupp, this works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same thing without an interactive rebase:

```
git branch some_temporary_name # to save your initial place
git reset --hard commit_you_want_to_change
...edit...
git commit --amend -m 'some message'
git rebase your_initial_branch_name some_temporary_name
git checkout your_initial_branch_name
git merge some_temporary_name # This will be a ff since you rebased
git branch -d some_temporary_name # remove unneeded branch
```

Comment: `git commit --fixup` plus `git rebase -i --autosquash` is much better (once more :) )

Comment: @CharlesB -- Won't git rebase -i --autosquash still bring up an editor?

Comment: Yes, but it's just for checking what it'll do, normally you don't have to edit anything. Just quit the editor. Think it as a confirmation dialog.

Comment: As mentioned above you can set the `EDITOR` env-variable to `/bin/true` to auto-accept it.