# How to change second last commit message which is not pushed yet

Tags: git, push, message, commit

I usually submit a list of commits for review. If I have the following commits:

> ```
> HEAD     (not pushed)
> Commit1  (not pushed) (Merged master here)
> Commit2
> Commit3
> ...
> ```

I know that I can modify head commit with git commit --amend. But how can I modify Commit1? given that it is not the HEAD commit and not pushed. ***git rebase does not show it in list of I enter git rebase -i HEAD~3.***

Comment: `git rebase -i Commit2` (with actual commit ID) doesn't work either?

Comment: Is it a merge commit? Maybe showing the output of this command would help: `git log --graph --oneline`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answers,
Actually the commit message I wanted to modify was merge commit and git rebase command does not show merge commits(if not pushed I guess) in *rebase HEAD~n* command and it was the main issue.

With the help of my colleague I was able to resolve by this command

> git rebase -i -p HEAD~3

where -p is for preserve merges Still not able to understand how this works fully, but it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you:

- don't want to do an integrative rebase (git rebase @~2)
- don't want to use a [set of commands to do the same non-interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10301716/6309)

You can use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) and [its callbacks](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#CALLBACKS), based on the content of the old message:

```sh
git-filter-repo --message-callback '
  if b"known content" in message:
    message = "New message\npossibly on\n several lines""
  return message'
```